# MySQL : Comparing two tables and modifying data into one

Tags: mysql

I have two tables into my database :

Table 1 : `hussainalotcallplan1`

```
Field    Type          Null    Key     Default  Extra   
-------  ------------  ------  ------  -------  --------
concode  varchar(20)   NO      PRI     (NULL)           
rate     double        YES             (NULL)           
vendor   varchar(100)  YES             (NULL)
diff     varchar(20)   YES             'NEW'
```

Table 2 : `tempratediff`

```
Field   Type         Null    Key     Default  Extra   
------  -----------  ------  ------  -------  --------
id      varchar(20)  NO      PRI     (NULL)           
rate    double       YES             (NULL)
```

I want to compare the rates of two tables for each id and put the results under `diff` column in `hussainalotcallplan1` table.

The two tables are related as `hussainalotcallplan1.concode = tempratediff.id`.

Sample Data: `hussainalotcallplan1`

`concode    rate    vendor    diff
 91         0.05    gbm       new`

`tempratediff`

`id    rate
 91   0.04`

I've to calculate the difference between two rates and insert the difference between them into `hussainalotcallplan1.diff`

I've Tried this : `update hussainalotcallplan1 set diff = SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT c.concode FROM hussainalotcallplan1 ) IN (SELECT t.id FROM tempratediff) THEN (c.rate-t.rate) END AS diff FROM hussainalotcallplan1 c, tempratediff t WHERE c.concode = t.id;`

Can anyone give me a clue about that? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Also there will be around 50,000 rows in each table. so please suggest an optimised query.

Comment: How the two table are related ?  there is related column ?

Comment: 1) Pls provide some sample data. 2) Pls provide expected output based on the sample data. 3) Pls share what you have tried. SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the update-join syntax:

```
UPDATE hussainalotcallplan1 h
JOIN   tempratediff t ON h.concode = t.id
SET    h.diff = h.rate - t.rate
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mureinik. Query works well.
33944 rows processed in 2.044 secs.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE hp 
SET hp.diff = CAST(hp.rate - td.rate AS VARCHAR)
    FROM hussainalotcallplan1 hp
    JOIN tempratediff td On hp.concode = td.id
```

I haven't tested this, but hope it's what you are after